# Fetching Records from multiple tenant in RavenDB

Tags: vb.net, ravendb

I am using EmbeddableDocumentStore to get records stored in raven.

Below VB.NET code is to access the raven data

```
Dim documentStore As EmbeddableDocumentStore = New EmbeddableDocumentStore()
documentStore.DataDirectory = "D:\Test\Server1"
documentStore.DefaultDatabase = "TestDB1"
documentStore.Url = "http://localhost:8585/"
documentStore.Initialize()
Dim session As Document.DocumentSession = documentStore.OpenSession()
Dim LineItems = session.Query(Of LineItem)()
```

Above code retrieves records from Database TestDB1, Similarly I have TestDB2 database

Now I have two question

1. How to access all records from `Server1.TestDB1.LineItem` and `Server1.TestDB2.LineItem`
2. How to access all records from `Server1.TestDB1.LineItem` and `Server2.TestDB1.LineItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You should be opening a session from within a [`Using` statment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).
- When you do so, you can pass a database name as a parameter to the `OpenSession` method.
- If you are regularly working with multiple databases, then you should probably pass the database name every time you open a session, instead of assigning a default database.
- An `EmbeddableDocumentStore` runs in the context of the process executing it, so you are not connecting to a server.  A URL is only used when you are using a regular `DocumentStore` and connecting to a RavenDB instance running elsewhere - in which case the `DataDirectory` would not be used.
- If you were using `DocumentStore` and connecting to servers elsewhere, then you would need two separate instances of `DocumentStore` - one for Server1 and another for Server2.
- However, it doesn't make any sense to run two separate `EmbeddableDocumentStore` instances in the same process.  It would work, but I can't see any advantage.